# How to hide unselected checknode in the jstree

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jstree

As Title, how I can hide the unselected checknode in the jstree. I want to show only checknodes and its parent in the jstree.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to filter out fully selected nodes and their potentially partially selected parents - if selected nodes have some unselected siblings. For all these nodes set `state.hidden` to `true`. Then redraw tree.

See code below, also check demo - [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/wyenqd1p/)

```
$("#yourTreeId")
    .jstree('get_json', '#', {
        flat: true
    })
    .forEach(function(node) {
        if (!node.state.selected && $('#' + node.a_attr.id).find('.jstree-undetermined').length === 0) {
            $("#yourTreeId").jstree('get_node', node).state.hidden = true;
        }
    });

$('#yourTreeId').jstree('redraw', true);
```

Comment: Hi Nikolay, if I don't want use the hide button and let it hide automatic, how can I do it? I had try remove the button click function but then useless. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: So how do you plan to trigger it? At the tree load?

Comment: Hihi, I had done it dy. It's mine code problem. Your's code can working. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, glad I helped!